# Can you change permission to all files except one directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions

Is there any way to change all files/directories permission except one single directory in a single Linux command line command?

Comment: `grep -v "directory to exclude"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you wish to set the permission bit 755 recursively for the contents of the folders in your current working directory, apart from the contents of the folder called *"nameOfFolderToBeExcluded"*:

```
 chmod 755 -R $(ls | awk '{if($1 != "nameOfFolderToBeExcluded"){ print $1 }}')
```

Comment: Why not just use `-I (--ignore)` option of `ls`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `find` to search for all the files that does not match the given filename and `exec` a command on all such files found as:

Assuming you need to exclude directory `test` and give file permissions 755 to all  other files and directores. This would be excecuted from the top of the tree.

```
find ! -name test -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

#### Tested

```
mtk@mtk4-laptop:$ touch a1.txt a2.txt a3.txt test
mtk@mtk4-laptop:$ ls -lrt
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mtk mtk 0 Sep 17 23:55 test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mtk mtk 0 Sep 17 23:55 a3.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mtk mtk 0 Sep 17 23:55 a2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mtk mtk 0 Sep 17 23:55 a1.txt
mtk@mtk4-laptop:$ find ! -name test -exec chmod 777 {} \;
mtk@mtk4-laptop:$ ls -lrt
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mtk mtk 0 Sep 17 23:55 test
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mtk mtk 0 Sep 17 23:55 a3.txt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mtk mtk 0 Sep 17 23:55 a2.txt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mtk mtk 0 Sep 17 23:55 a1.txt*
mtk@mtk4-laptop:$
```

The file permissions for file `test` remained unchanged. Same is applicable for directories.

Comment: This only exclude files by that name -- not folders.   Try `mkdir test` + `touch a1.txt a2.txt a3.txt`, and then execute the command.

Answer (score 3):

What shell?

If you're running [bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (likely if you're on Linux), you can check out extglob, which gives you more options for globbing, including the "negative glob" `!()`

```
shopt -s extglob
chmod 774 !(file-to-ignore)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` more simply like this:

```
find <from_where_to_change> -not -path "*/<excluded_dir_name>*" [-and -not -path "*/<another_excluded_dir_if_you_want>*"] -exec chown <user>[:<group>] {} \;
```

In my case it was:

```
find /data/project -not -path "*/.svn*" -exec chown :www-data {} \;
```

This way I changed group on folder /data/project recursively, except all folders ".svn" recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple command will do :-

```bsh
chmod 755 /x/y/!(abc)
```

Where `x/y/z` = path.

`abc` = name for the folder/file to be excluded

Answer (score 0):

Even easier way with basic commands:

```
chmod 755 -R $(ls -A|grep -v 'directory_name_to_exclude/*')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using below command, it will give files 644 and directory 755 to all files and directory in Present working directory but will exclude var directory to provide permission.

```
find . -not -path "*/var*" -type f -exec chmod -c 0644 {} \; && find . -not -path "*/var*" -type d -exec chmod -c 0775 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

And more easily with basic commands:

```
chmod -R 755 $(ls -I folder_excluded)
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain it. Otherwise it may get deleted.